# Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] : I can't access wifi on my debian

Tags: debian, wifi, wlan, iwlwifi

I use debian 10. My wlan driver doesn't show up in ifconfig and I can't establish wireless connection in any way. It looks like my wifi card and necessary drivers are in place.

**sudo ifconfig**

```
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.33  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::60e:3cff:fe8f:ca7d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 04:0e:3c:8f:ca:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 37635  bytes 47303064 (45.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11854  bytes 1668922 (1.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2162  bytes 173946 (169.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2162  bytes 173946 (169.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo lshw -C network**

```
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f1210000-f1213fff
```

**sudo rfkill list**

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Welcome, could you add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3`

Comment: Sure I just edited my post with the output. @GAD3R

Comment: Install the `firmware-iwlwifi` after adding `non-free` to your `sources.list`, [installation guide here](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#supported).

Comment: @GAD3R I did, it did not work.

Comment: Installing `firmware-iwlwifi` did appear to work for me. After doing so on my Debian 10, I now see a 'wlo1' when running `ip addr`.